# RAM optimized for AMD systems?

Tags: memory

I've been told by G.Skill, that my RAM is actually optimized for Intel systems. Is this even possible?

By now, I'm also looking for new RAM, and would like to know if there are any brands or types that are AMD optimized?

Comment: Just thought DDR2 vs. DDR3, but it is --way-- more complicated... http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/36719.htm

Comment: AMD sells their own ram IIRC, under the radion brand

Comment: That's a new line of RAM, haven't seen it in any stores though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. AMD and Intel have similar instruction sets for most operations. However, they each have their own 'optimised' instructions for doing particular things. Saying that their RAM is optimised for one chipset or another means that is supports these extended instruction sets. G.Skill makes RAM that works in both systems, though one model might work better in Intel systems while another model works better in AMD systems.

The best thing you can do is to look up what RAM is supported/recommended by your motherboard manufacturer. Check the documentation or manufacturers website for specific information.

Comment: ram doesn't have an instruction set.

Comment: The RAM itself might not have an 'instruction set' itself. However, it may or may not support the operations that the memory controller on the CPU is trying to perform.